# Question on SE site being reported as a phishing site?

Tags: support, security

See this question on Meta Security SE: [security se reported by chrome as a suspected phishing site](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/security-se-reported-by-chrome-as-a-suspected-phishing-site)

They mention this question on Security SE: [Is the Facebook login form using SSL without https in the URL?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/is-facebook-com-login-form-using-ssl-without-https)

Note the dates of that question.  I'm still getting the error.  Do I just have a caching problem, or is Google still flagging this for other people?

Comment: It's still flagging it.  I just tried it and got the warning.  I used the "Report an error" link.

Comment: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsecurity.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F7974%2Fis-facebook-com-login-form-using-ssl-without-https

Comment: I'm also getting this warning using iPod touch on iOS 5

Comment: Nothing unusual viewing it through the Android default browser.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome do not report anything on that link (anymore).

Comment: I'm still getting a warning on Chrome 14

Comment: I flagged it as a false alert using Google's report form, and posted a link to this discussion. We will see whether that helps any

Comment: Flagged as a false alert, just doing my part =D

Comment: This seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is out of our control.

Basically, it looks like some combination of "security", "facebook-com", and "https" gets Google all hot and bothered about phishing.  It's... understandable, although incorrect.

All we can do is suggest people report these false positives to Google, a number of the dev team have.